# Are SharePinters included in this site's scope?

Tags: discussion

Just curious if SharePinters are to be included here. It'd be a shame if they aren't. They're a fun group and they usually know a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clearify on @alexangas answer: no, SharePint (drinking beer talking SharePoint) is not in scope :)

Comment: Maybe we can talk about beer and SharePoint in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint)!

Answer (score 3):

We welcome anyone willing to answer (or ask) questions about SharePoint in accordance with our [faq](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq)!